# Why double a = 8/3 return 2?

Tags: c#, .net, double

I have the following code :

```
double a = 8/ 3;
Response.Write(a);
```

It returns the value 2. Why? I need at least one decimal digit. Something like 2.6, or 2.66. How can I get such results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
double a = 8/3.0d;
```

or

```
double a = 8.0d/3;
```

to get a precise answer.

**Since in expression `a = 8/3` both the operands are `int` so the result is `int` irrespective of the fact that it is being stored in a `double`. The results are always in the higher data type of operands**

### EDIT

To answer

> 8 and 3 are get from variable. Can I do a sort of cast?

In case the values are coming from a variable you can cast one of the operands into `double` like:

```
int b = 8;
int c = 3;
double a = ((double) b) /c;
```

Comment: 8 and 3 are get from variable. Can I do a sort of cast?

Answer (score 3):

Because the calculation are being done in integer type not double. To make it double use:

```
double a = 8d/ 3d;
Response.Write(a);
```

Or

```
double a = 8.0/ 3.0;
Response.Write(a);
```

One of your operands should be explicitly marked as double either by using `d` or specifying a decimal point `0`

or if you need you can cast them to double before the calculations. You can cast either one or both operands to double.

```
double a = ((double) 8)/((double)3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its making a rounding towards  minus, its the way its implemented in the framework. However if you specify the precision by using the above example:

```
double a = 8/3.0d;
```

then rounding is no longer performed.

Or in simple terms you assigned an integer value to a double, thats why the rounding was performed in the first place. It saw an operation with integers.

Comment: It's not rounding. It's performing the calculation on two `int`s and returns an `int` (2) that is implicitly casted as a `double`.

Comment: i understand that, but because the calculation is made in ints the result does not return an exact int so it returns 2.6, but as you stated the calculation is made in ints so if the result is not an int its rounded so it resembles an int. Correct?

Comment: Well, technically, the remainder is just skipped. No rounding is performed. http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/divide.030.html

Answer (score 0):

because 8 and 3 are integer numbers and interpreter rounds it to 2.
You can simply advise to interpreter that you numbers are floating numbers:

```
double a = (double)8 / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Coz 8 and 3 both ints. And int's division operator with two ints in it returns int as well. (F12 when the cursor is on slash sign).